# How to predict on one data record if used shuffle_batch to train the model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a model with CNN, used `shuffle_batch` to deal with large data files, and I set a batch size 64 before training. It seems the batch size could not be changed during or after the training, then how to use the trained model to predict on only one data record, with fixed batch size?

Used placeholder for `batch_size`, code is as follows:

```py
def train(target_path, vocab_processor):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        **batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='batch_size')**
        data_batch, label_batch = read_data_from_tfrecords(target_path, batch_size)
        session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
            allow_soft_placement=FLAGS.allow_soft_placement,
            log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)
        sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
        with sess.as_default():
            cnn = TextCNN(
                sequence_length=data_batch.shape[1],
                num_classes=label_batch.shape[1],
                vocab_size=len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_),
                embedding_size=FLAGS.embedding_dim,
                filter_sizes=list(map(int, FLAGS.filter_sizes.split(","))),
                num_filters=FLAGS.num_filters,
                input_x=data_batch,
                input_y=label_batch,
                l2_reg_lambda=FLAGS.l2_reg_lambda
            )
            # Define Training procedure
            global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
            grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cnn.loss)
            train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)
            # Keep track of gradient values and sparsity (optional)
            grad_summaries = []
            for g, v in grads_and_vars:
                if g is not None:
                    grad_hist_summary = tf.summary.histogram("{}/grad/hist".format(v.name), g)
                    sparsity_summary = tf.summary.scalar("{}/grad/sparsity".format(v.name), tf.nn.zero_fraction(g))
                    grad_summaries.append(grad_hist_summary)
                    grad_summaries.append(sparsity_summary)
            grad_summaries_merged = tf.summary.merge(grad_summaries)
            # Output directory for models and summaries
            timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
            out_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, "runs", timestamp))
            print("Writing to {}\n".format(out_dir))
            # Summaries for loss and accuracy
            loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar("loss", cnn.loss)
            acc_summary = tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", cnn.accuracy)
            # Train Summaries
            train_summary_op = tf.summary.merge([loss_summary, acc_summary, grad_summaries_merged])
            train_summary_dir = os.path.join(out_dir, "summaries", "train")
            train_summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(train_summary_dir, sess.graph)
            # Checkpoint directory. Tensorflow assumes this directory already exists so we need to create it
            checkpoint_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(out_dir, "checkpoints"))
            checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "model")
            if not os.path.exists(checkpoint_dir):
                os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir)
            saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), max_to_keep=FLAGS.num_checkpoints)
            init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                            tf.local_variables_initializer())
            sess.run(init)
            # sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
            try:
                while not coord.should_stop():
                    **feed_dict = {
                        cnn.dropout_keep_prob: FLAGS.dropout_keep_prob,
                        batch_size: 64
                    }**
                    _, step, summaries, loss, accuracy = sess.run(
                        [train_op, global_step, train_summary_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy], feed_dict)
                    time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
                    print("{}: step {}, loss {:g}, acc {:g}".format(time_str, step, loss, accuracy))
                    train_summary_writer.add_summary(summaries, step)
                    current_step = tf.train.global_step(sess, global_step)
                    if current_step % FLAGS.checkpoint_every == 0:
                        path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_prefix, global_step=current_step)
                        print("Saved model checkpoint to {}\n".format(path))
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print("done training")
            finally:
                coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
            sess.close()
```

mistakes:

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/code/error-classify/cnn_classify/test_train.py", line 247, in <module>
        train(tfRecorder_path, vocab_processor)
      File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/code/error-classify/cnn_classify/test_train.py", line 82, in train
        num_threads=2)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 1220, in shuffle_batch
        name=name)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 765, in _shuffle_batch
        if capacity <= min_after_dequeue:
      File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 499, in __bool__
        raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
    TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your fixed batch size by a placeholder, that you set to 64 for training and to whatever you need when infering.

```py
batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (), name="batch_size")
tf.train.shuffle_batch (..., batch_size = batch_size, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for apply. But where should I place the ` feed_dict = {'batch_size': 32}` ? I placed it before sess.run() and got a mistake which said raise TypeError("Using a tf.Tensor` as a Python bool is not allowed. "`

Comment: Could you post a more complete portion of your code as an edit to your question or as a new question, so that we can have a look at your issue?

Comment: I've added the code after the question. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with this set `allow_smaller_final_batch=True`. 
Generally train.batch should be used instead of shuffle_batch when testing.

Failed when using placeholder, have not figured out why